# How to check the available free space in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am newly starting on mongodb. I know that by default, mongodb pre allocated data files in the order of 64MB, 128MB, 256MB, ....2GB, 2GB, 2GB....etc

Now let us supposed i have a mongo instance that is preallocated with 
64MB and 128MB for each of the different collections.
Now I would like to know the below

- How to check the available free space in the 128MB file of each collections?
- How to check the total size of all the collections, data bases?
- How to check the total available free space out of allocated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking free space in the internal storage files of mongo is not something you normally (or at all) do.

Mongo provides a number of functions which you can use to [check the size of collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-CheckingSizeofaCollection) and some [helpful scripts](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-Helpfulscripts) demonstrating how to run the functions on each database on the server.

You can also wrap such functions in a script to make reading easier, such as [this script](https://github.com/AD7six/mongo-scripts/blob/master/collectionSizes.js) which lists the size and counts for all collections in a database.

Comment: Ya... I agree with the first statememt. in case of pre allocation it can hardly be a value less than 2GB.